# Dry-run a potentially dangerous script?

Tags: linux, bash

A predecessor of mine installed a crappy piece of software on an old machine (running Linux) which I've inherited. Said crappy piece of software installed flotsam all over the place, and also is sufficiently bloated that I want it off ASAP -- it no longer has any functional purpose since we've moved on to better software.

Vendor provided an uninstall script. Not trusting the crappy piece of software, I opened the uninstall script in an editor (a 200+ line Bash monster), and it starts off something like this:

```
SWROOT=`cat /etc/vendor/path.conf`
...
rm -rf $SWROOT/bin
...
```

It turns out that `/etc/vendor/path.conf` is missing. Don't know why, don't know how, but it is. If I had run this lovely little script, it would have deleted the `/bin` folder, which would have had rather amusing implications. Of course this script required `root` to run!

I've dealt with this issue by just manually running all the install commands (guh) where sensible. This kind of sucked because I had to interpolate all the commands manually. In general, is there some sort of way I can "dry run" a script to have it dump out all the commands it *would* execute, without it actually executing them?

Comment: No, `bash` doesn't provide any _dry run_ functionality.

Comment: Make e.g. a Python script that makes each line `echo "line"`. Then run it.

Comment: Is there another shell that does?

Comment: vendor should get slapped

Comment: that uninstall script might be suitable for thedailywtf.com

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for cloning your machine to a virtual machine (see Virtualbox) and running it there to try it out. Always a great way to try out suspect software.

Comment: Wipe the drive and start with a fresh install. You have backups of any necessary data, right? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try running the script under Kornshell. When you execute a script with `ksh -D`, it reads the commands and checks them for syntax, but doesn't execute them. Combine that with `set -xv`, and you'll print out the commands that will be executed.

You can also use `set -n` for the same effect. Kornshell and BASH are fairly compatible with each other. If it's a pure Bourne shell script, both Kornshell and BASH will execute it pretty much the same.

You can also run `ksh -u` which will cause unset shell variables to cause the script to fail. However, that wouldn't have caught the catless cat of a nonexistent file. In that case, the shell variable was set. It was set to null.

Of course, you could run the script under a restricted shell too, but that's probably not going to uninstall the package.

That's the best you can probably do.

Comment: Oh, very nice! I have never used `ksh`, but it looks like it's a good time to look into this.

Comment: Actually, a good time to look into Kornshell was about 20 years ago. Kornshell was the first *super shell* based upon Bourne shell syntax. Kornshell 88 (as in 1988) was the first major release. Kornshell was owned by AT&T and not originally open sourced (although freely available). Then, it became open source under the CPL license which is incompatible with the GPL license, and thus Linux and GNU. (Don't get me started about the _license wars_.) However, there are a few nice KSH features that never made it into BASH, and the *dry-run* was one of them.

Comment: While `-D` _implies_ `-n`, it serves a different purpose. `-n` for syntax checking only is also supported in `bash` and `zsh`. Adding `-x` to `-n` offers no benefit at all, because - by design - nothing is _executed_.
Adding `-v` offers _may_ offer a _limited_ benefit: it will print the source code up to the point of a syntax error, if there is one - otherwise it's effectively just a `cat` of the script. That said, `-n` always prints out the offending line number.
In short: no dry-run functionality, syntax checking without execution is all you get - whether in `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`.

Answer (score 18):

**`bash` does *not* offer dry-run functionality** (and neither do `ksh`, `zsh`, or any other shell I know).

It seems to me that **offering such a feature in a shell would be next to impossible**: state changes would have to be *simulated* and any command invoked - whether built in or external - would have to be aware of these simulations.

The closest thing that `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` offer is the ability to ***syntax-check* a script** without executing it, **via option `-n`**:

```
bash -n someScript  # syntax-check a script, without executing it.
```

- If there are no syntax errors, there will be no output, and the exit code will be 0.
- If there are syntax errors, analysis will stop at the *first* error, an error message including the line number is written to stderr, and the exit code will be:

  - `2` in `bash`
  - `3` in `ksh`
  - `1` in `zsh`

---

Separately, `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` offer **debugging options**:

- `-v` to print each raw *source code line*<sup>[1]</sup>
  to stderr before it is executed.
- `-x` to print each *expanded simple command* to stderr before it is executed (env. var. `PS4` allows tweaking the output format).

---

**Combining `-n` with `-v` and/or `-x` offers little benefit:**

- With `-n` specified, `-x` has no effect at all, because nothing is being *executed*.
- With `-n` specified, `-v` will effectively simply *print* the source code.

  - If there is a syntax error, there *may* be benefit in the source code getting print *up to the point where the error occurs*; keep in mind, though that the error message produced by
    `-n` always includes the offending line number.

---

<sup>[1] *Typically*, it is individual *lines* that are printed, but the true unit is however many lines a given command - which may be a compound command such as `while` or a command list (such as a pipeline) - spans.</sup>